# Typescript type within object array notation

Tags: typescript, graphql

I cannot understand this code I see in a file. What on earth would this be doing?

```
const user = rowData as NonNullable<ApiResult["getUsers"]["data"][number]["users"]>[number];
```

How can you use a type (number) to look at the property of an object? Note that ApiResult is some graphql generated type and that this code is found within a `renderCell` for a mui data grid `GridColumns` array.

Comment: `"getUsers"` is also a type; it's a string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  The notation `T[K]` is an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) where `T` is an object-like type and `K` a keylike *type* assignable to `keyof T`, and then `T[K]` is the value types you'd get from indexing into an object of type `T` with a key of type `K`.  If `foo` is of type `Foo`, and `k` is of type `"x"`, and `foo[k]` is of type `string`, then `Foo["x"]` is of type `string`.

Comment: Umm. Uhh.. Yes.. Yes of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can you use a type (number) to look at the property of an object?

An array is an object, and has values at numbered keys, so `ArrayType[number]` would be a union of the types of each element of the array.

---

[`NonNullable<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) Constructs a type by excluding `null` and `undefined` from `Type`.

Here's an example of what the data structure is expected to extend, using an arbitrary `User` type. You can visit the TS playground link and mouseover the lettered type names `A` through `F` to see what the IntelliSense thinks the types are:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=9&ssc=7&pln=9&pc=45#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gKClA9gOwgC4oByAFQAsBLOKW0gbmymAHdcTThLpgBDRAHMIwCABNW4CE0wBfZplCQoAQTDUAShDgBXADbBUGFiODwkcElhw5x-ASVWJE-EAB4btnLoSIrai5u7haIAHxQAD5Q+Ab6UVC6+OIQAGbUhOLM3nJh2VAK8oopAMb6gtAlBHBGiLhsACIO-CRJANb49fjMVfg1iX7GdY3NUPx0AHIEE3H8AEb6EO7qWjoGwADaAERmoXBbALrb9gKHG7EAtnNIR1u+lodh57pXN4oA9O9QEAAe-BcZaA0JCCEqUEBEJTSNTGFbaPSGKEqABCsI08PW212fn2ByR0AAwmjVgjNjtRHszlsTvxDvioA1iRjDFiKTiqTSzpdrog8cpoABRJlrFnk8zs26co7cm7be7+On8qAAMWMU3wM305QWSzhIrJ2IekuaXJePNu8txTxlvMwQA)

```ts
type User = {
  one: 'This is';
  two: 'the targeted type';
};

type ApiResult = {
  getUsers: {
    data: Array<{
      users: Array<User> | null | undefined;
    }>;
  };
};

declare const rowData: unknown;
const user = rowData as NonNullable<ApiResult["getUsers"]["data"][number]["users"]>[number];

// examine hierarchy:
type A = ApiResult
type B = ApiResult["getUsers"]
type C = ApiResult["getUsers"]["data"]
type D = ApiResult["getUsers"]["data"][number]
type E = ApiResult["getUsers"]["data"][number]["users"]
type F = NonNullable<ApiResult["getUsers"]["data"][number]["users"]>[number]
```

Comment: Okay.. thanks. Seems like pure insanity to me.